# Reading a file into array with mutable array in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to read a file into array, by using mutable array in Objective C like this:

```
NSCharacterSet *newlineCharSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSMutableArray *myStr = [data componentSeparatedByCharactersInSet: newlineCharSet];
```

And this is the warning that I've got :

```
Incompatible pointer type initializing "NSMutableArray" with an expression of type "NSArray"
```

The reason why I used NSMutableArray is because later I'm going to convert all the elements inside the array to lowercase. Would it be possible to fix the warning and still satisfy the condition to use mutable array ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` returns an `NSArray`, not a mutable array. To satisfy the compiler (and actually provide you with a mutable array), simple create a mutable copy:

```
NSMutableArray *myStr = [[data componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:newlineCharSet] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 3):

`componentSeparatedByCharactersInSet` returns an `NSArray` object.. If you want an `NSMutableArray` Object instead than you need to create an `NSMutableArray` from it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *myStr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[data componentSeparatedByCharactersInSet: newlineCharSet]];
```